# CEFSharp bound object lost when new website is loaded

Tags: cefsharp

I am using CEFSharp in one of my projects and all works perfectly fine so far.
I am still on V63 of CEFSharp (never touch a running system :-) )

I am using it in VB.NET

The bound object is created after CEFSharp initialisation within Public Sub New() as follows:

```
 CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = True
        Dim obj As New BoundObject()
        obj.browser = browser
        browser.RegisterJsObject("bound", obj)
        AddHandler browser.LoadingStateChanged, AddressOf obj.Browser_LoadingStateChanged
```

I am then after each "LoadingStateChanged" event of the browser execute a  JS script with browser.ExecuteScriptAsync.....its basically an event listner that will fire the bound object when the event occurs (e.g. a mousclick).

This also so far works 100% OK....the event fires and calls the bound object and passes a variable to my VB.NET code via the bound object.

Now my problem is that after I load a new page the bound object is lost.

The event listner will try to call the bound object but I just get an error like "Uncaught ReferenceError: bound is not defined"

Looks like be loading a new page inside CEFSharp the bound object is lost.

I triead the above initialisation code also with FrameLoadEnd event instead, but it behaves exactly the same as LoadingStateChanged event.

Any clue anyone how I can handle (or renew) the bound object whenever I load a new website?

Thanks

Update:
In the meantime I tried the binding method V2 as recommended.
Using the following code for testing purpose:

```
'########### TEST CODE  TEST CODE   TEST CODE  ##################
            'try to use new binding V2 method by calling CefSharp.BindObjectAsync:
            browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("CefSharp.BindObjectAsync(""myObject"");")
            'now register object:
            browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("myObject", New BoundObject(), True)
            'now do test execution of myObject:
            browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("myObject(""test"");")
```

But still struggeling to get it working :-(

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_CefSharpSettings_LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled.htm

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript

Comment: Thanks @amaitland - the first link makes it very clear that its a feature not a bug :-)  However I am struggeling to implement this in VB.NET and convert my current legacy method code into a working new method code.   Is there a possibility to provide some of those basic examples in VB.NET? I am struggeling to convert it from C# to VB.NET.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any `VB.Net` examples. I avoid the language where possible.

Comment: @amaitland - after reading the documentation at least three times it seems that I was trying the wrong thing.  If I understand correctly, now in the new way the binding needs to be initiated in JavaScript on the target website? In case I have no control over that website can I then just inject the Async Function using 'browser.ExecuteScriptAsync' to inject it, as I just do with any other JS?

Comment: Yes, binding is initiated in `Javascript`. Yes you can inject the javascript calling `ExecuteScriptAsync`. Depending on your usage scenario you can use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_JavascriptBindingExtensions_EnsureObjectBoundAsync.htm you would need to upgrade to a newer version for this extension method. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2362#issuecomment-387609300 and https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/67/CefSharp/JavascriptBindingExtensions.cs#L49

Comment: You obviously don't have to use the `EnsureObjectBoundAsync ` extension method. You can implement your own specific method.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Have only been able to test it today. I try to initiate the binding after browser.LoadingStateChanged event fired and using the test code I've inserted above into my original post, but when the last line is executed y see in the debugging console "Uncaught ReferenceError: myObject is not defined" - looks like the binding was not successful? Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Register your object first. `BindObjectAsync` returns a promise, you should wait for it to complete before attempting to access the object. You need to call a method on the object, not just the object it's self.

Comment: It works now as suggested. Thanks for you patience and help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last sugestion of amaitland solved the problem. it works now nicely across various sites. In principle I just replaced this two lines in my original working code:

```
Dim obj As New BoundObject()
obj.browser = browser
'browser.RegisterJsObject("bound", obj)    'replaced by next line (JS binding V2)
browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("bound", obj, True, Nothing)
AddHandler browser.LoadingStateChanged, AddressOf obj.Browser_LoadingStateChanged
```

And then later within the Sub that handles the `browser_LoadingStateChangedAsync` event I just added this line beofre any other injected JS:

```
 'use new binding V2 method by calling CefSharp.BindObjectAsync:
 browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("CefSharp.BindObjectAsync(""bound"");")
```

I hope this helps others using CEFsharpin VB.NET if they come across the same problem.

Comment: The official documentation is at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to do the same thing in C# (like me):

```
Browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("myObject", interf, true);
Browser.LoadingStateChanged += (s, a) =>
{
    if (a.IsLoading) return;
    Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("CefSharp.BindObjectAsync(\"myObject\");");
};
```

I've added checking the `IsLoading` state, as there is no reason to bind the object when the browser *starts* loading (at least in my use case).